# Is SetTimeOut a good Solution in Parse Server?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I need to run a code that triggers various pushs for users to depend on the status of an object.

As if it were a cab dispatch application, I'm sending the push as the race is not accepted by some taxi driver.

I'm thinking of using SetTimeOut to perform a query and check if the race was accepted or not, if it was not I'm sending the pushs by users distance.

Comment: you may want to just run a periodic (every 30 seconds?) script that checks for any unaccepted dispatches.  You could do it with a settimeout, but then if that host is restarted.....

Comment: yes, I run the script less than 30 seconds.

Comment: so you could setup a cron job on your server to run every 30 seconds that querries for any open requests that have not had a dispatch accepted.